# Conceptual explanation for why projection from sphere to cylinder is a volume-preserving map

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Regard $S^n$ and $S^1 \times \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ as codimension-$1$ submanifolds of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, equipped with the volume forms they inherit from $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.  Letting $X = S^n \setminus 0 \times S^{n-2}$, define $f\colon X \rightarrow S^1 \times \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ via the formula
$$f(x_1,\ldots,x_{n+1}) = \left(\frac{x_1}{\sqrt{x_1^1+x_2^2}},\frac{x_2}{\sqrt{x_1^1+x_2^2}},x_3,\ldots,x_{n+1}\right).$$
It goes back to Archimedes that $f$ is a volume-preserving map onto its image.  I can do the calculation with the formulas and verify this, but it seems mysterious to me.  Does anyone know a more geometric or conceptual explanation?  There are vague descriptions all over the web (for instance, in the "geometric proof" of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_of_an_n-ball#Geometric_proof) wikipedia article), but I have trouble turning these into precise mathematics.

Comment: Does this help?  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/113780/proof-without-words-for-surface-area-of-a-sphere

Comment: @StevenLandsburg: David Speyer's answer is basically what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Comment: These days, it's a combination of simple geometry and simple trigonometry. However, Van der Waerden presented the two original Archimedes proofs, beautiful! One based on mechanics, followed by a purely geometric argument. Of course, this is true only for $S^2$, not for other dimensions.